# Spring batch integration MessageSource<InputStream> to Joblaunch request

Tags: spring-batch

I am planning to use S3Streaming message source to process the import file (xml)received in S3. I am not sure how to transform MessageSource to job launch request as job parameter doesn't support parameters other than primitive type, please throw some light on how to proceed on this
- Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you want to create a `JobLaunchRequest` from a `MessageSource<InputStream>`. Can you share your config? What prevents you from creating a `JobParameters` instance with the URL to the XML file and then create the `JobLaunchRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to pass the InputStream payload to an `ItemReader`, no, that can't be done with a `JobLauncher`.

Instead, the `ItemReader` itself needs to open the input stream (perhaps using a Spring Integration `SftpRemoteFileTemplate`).

Just pass the information (filename, server, credentials, etc) in the `JobParameters` and close the SI input stream payload without reading.

Comment: The Spring Cloud AWS provides an `S3` resource protocol implementation: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_resource_handling. So, you can send an URL for the remote S3 file and Spring Batch can handle it over it resource abstraction mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan Gary Russell  ! I started from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws. I want an inbound adaptor polling S3 on my bucket, and kick in the job which takes S3 file as resource(as you mentioned) and process it. Inbound adaptors mentioned in the above doc, one is giving me message of File and another one as InputStream. Is there anyway to get only URL in the inbound adaptors?

Comment: You can build it from the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY` and `FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE` headers